# Getting <generator object <genexpr> at 0x1193417d8> as output

Tags: python-3.x

```
#Reading files with txt extension
def get_sentences():
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk("/Users/Documents/test1"):
        for file in files:
            if file.endswith(".txt"):
                x_ = codecs.open(os.path.join(root,file),"r", "utf-8-sig")
                for lines in x_.readlines():
                    yield lines
formoreprocessing = get_sentences()

#Tokenizing sentences of the text files

from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize
for i in formoreprocessing:
    raw_docs = sent_tokenize(i)
    tokenized_docs = [sent_tokenize(i) for sent in raw_docs]

'''Removing Stop Words'''
stopword_removed_sentences = []
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
stopset = set(stopwords.words("English"))
def strip_stopwords(sentence):
    return ' '.join(word for word in sentence.split() if word not in stopset)
stopword_removed_sentences = (strip_stopwords(sentence) for sentence in raw_docs)
print(stopword_removed_sentences)
```

The above code is not printing what it is supposed to be. Instead it is throwing:
 at 0x1193417d8>
as output. What is the mistake here?
I am using python 3.5.

Comment: "not printing what it is supposed to be." **what do you expect it to print instead**? If you expect a list then use [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) instead of a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3.5/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions), if you expect something else please specify what you expect.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generator Expressions vs. List Comprehension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/47789/generator-expressions-vs-list-comprehension)

Comment: It is supposed to print the text that it receive as input from tokenized_docs, after removing stoo words from it.  But the expression  print(stopword_removed_sentences) is not doing so.

Comment: have you tried using list comprehension to define `stopword_removed_sentences` with `[]` around the expression instead of `()` or `print(list(stopwod_removed_sentences))` as JohnColeman has suggested?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the final answer, the provides the best result resolving the problem that i have mentioned in my previous comment.

```
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize
raw_docs = sent_tokenize(''.join(formoreprocessing))
#print(raw_docs)
tokenized_docs = [sent_tokenize(''.join(formoreprocessing)) for sent in raw_docs]
#Removing Stop Words
stopword_removed_sentences = []
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
stopset = set(stopwords.words("English"))
def strip_stopwords(sentence):
    return ' '.join(word for word in sentence.split() if word not in stopset)
stopword_removed_sentences = (strip_stopwords(sentence) for sentence in raw_docs)
print(list(stopword_removed_sentences))
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `print(list(stopword_removed_sentences))`. This turns the generator into a list before printing it